# Can I return multiple lists from a WCF Service?

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, list

I have written a wcf service in c#.  From Jquery I call the service and return a list.  I now want to return multiple lists.  Is this possible?

The list is being passed back as Json.  Can I somehow create an array of lists?  Sorry I'm new to this so this question may be way too vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return whatever you want.  Return a `List<List<T>>` if you want.  Return a complex type `SomeCustomType` that contains members, each of type `List<T>`.  Your restriction is that a function can only return **ONE** value (a C# restriction more than a WCF restriction, but a valid restriction nonetheless).  Besides that, you're free to make that one value pretty much as complex as you want.